# removing SpriteNodes after a period of time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm creating a whack-a-mole game, and I would like the moles to be removed after a period of time. I have a few timer functions set up to gradually speed up the spawning of the moles, and I have a feeling that the timer functions would also be used to remove the moles as well. As the game progresses, I would also like the time that the moles are "above ground" to decrease. I know how to remove the node from the scene, but not in a way that would gradually increase over time. I think this would also help with the spawning of the moles, because right now I'm using a really inefficient way because I couldn't figure out how to make a gradual decrease in spawning time.

This is my update function where I speed up the spawning of the moles.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if score == 0 && firstTimerDone == 0{
        moleTimer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: Selector("createMole"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        firstTimerDone = 1
    } else if score == 10 && secondTimerDone == 0{
        moleTimer1.invalidate()
        moleTimer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.3, target: self, selector: Selector("createMole"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        secondTimerDone = 1
    } else if score == 20 && thirdTimerDone == 0{
        moleTimer2.invalidate()
        moleTimer3 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.1, target: self, selector: Selector("createMole"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        thirdTimerDone = 1
    }
}
```